# Global libraries in Intellij IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, java

I have added a Java library in the Intellij IDE, but every time I start a new Java project I can't import this library, and have to set it up over again.

This is a screenshot from Intellij Project Structure:

[image: Global Library]

The library is there, but when I try to import it I get an error:

[image: Importing library]

Comment: What do you mean by *"but every time I start a new program I can't import this library"*?

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I meant every time I start a new Java project, I have edited my question now. Thank you for pointing that out Abimaran!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting up a Global Library ensures that the library is defined, however it is *not* automatically added as a dependency to new projects.

You must go into `Project Structure` -> `Modules`, click the `Dependencies` tab and press the green `+` to add it to your project.

Or, instead, (and if IntelliJ is smart enough) after hitting `F2` to navigate to one of the compile errors in your source code, `Alt-enter` might allow a quick fix to add the dependency (you'd have to try it...).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot (although the quick fix did not work, unfortunately). Now, what is the difference between dependencies and importing a library?

Comment: Libraries basically just point to a jar (or a folder of jars) some place. Keeping in mind that your project may consist of multiple modules, and not all modules may need to use a particular library, you must then manage the `dependencies` of each module individually for it to be "available" in each particular module. Sometimes, IntelliJ might ask you along the lines of "hey, you just created a library, shall I add a dependency to the module you are working in?" - just answer "yes" if applicable